# IPv6 route based VPN client with Strongswan, packets arrive but not received by application

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ipv6, strongswan

I'm trying to set up a linux client PC with a route based VPN tunnel using strongswan and an XFRM interface, with IPv6 (end to end).

strongswan 5.8.2, linux kernel 5.15.0

[An aside - I've tried an identical test using all IPv4 addresses (end to end), and everything works correctly]

Client PC 2001:3::3 <-> 2001:3::2 Router 2001:4::2 <-> 2001:4::200 Remote PC

swanctl.conf on Client PC:

```
connections {
    ipsec-ikev2-vpn {
        version = 2
        encap = no
        dpd_delay = 300s
        local_addrs = 2001:3::3
        remote_addrs = 2001:3::2
        proposals = aes256gcm16-sha384-prfsha384-ecp384
        local {
            id = Site_B
            auth = pubkey
            certs= ca.pem
        }
        remote {
            auth = pubkey
        }
        children {
            child1 {
                mode = tunnel
                local_ts = ::/0
                remote_ts = ::/0
                if_id_in = 99
                if_id_out = 99
                start_action = start
                dpd_action = clear
                esp_proposals = aes256gcm16
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I create a XFRM interface on the Client PC (enp4s0np0 is the 2001:3::3 interface), give it an IPv6 address, and configure a route to the remote lan:

```
ip -6 link add xfrm-1 type xfrm dev enp4s0np0 if_id 99
ip -6 addr add 2001:2::1/128 dev xfrm-1
ip -6 link set xfrm-1 up
ip -6 route add 2001:4::/64 dev xfrm-1
```

Then I start strongswan on the client PC, which establishes the tunnel ok

Now this is the problem - When I try to ping the Remote PC from the Client PC, no replies are received:

```
ping6 2001:4::200
PING 2001:4::200(2001:4::200) 56 data bytes
^C
--- 2001:4::200 ping statistics ---
773 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 790532ms
```

So I'm trying to find the reason why the ping doesn't work, and fix it...

tcpdump on the XFRM interface shows the replies are arriving (on client PC):

```
tcpdump -i xfrm-1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on xfrm-1, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
13:16:00.352995 IP6 2001:2::1 > 2001:4::200: ICMP6, echo request, seq 39, length 64
13:16:00.353614 IP6 2001:4::200 > 2001:2::1: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 39, length 64
13:16:01.380979 IP6 2001:2::1 > 2001:4::200: ICMP6, echo request, seq 40, length 64
13:16:01.381378 IP6 2001:4::200 > 2001:2::1: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 40, length 64
13:16:02.400866 IP6 2001:2::1 > 2001:4::200: ICMP6, echo request, seq 41, length 64
13:16:02.401506 IP6 2001:4::200 > 2001:2::1: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 41, length 64
```

Routing (on client PC):

```
ip -6 route show
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:2::1 dev xfrm-1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:3::/64 dev enp4s0np0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
2001:4::/64 dev xfrm-1 metric 1024 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp4s0np0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev xfrm-1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlo1 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
```

packets are passing through the tunnel ok (client PC):

```
ip -s xfrm state
src 2001:3::3 dst 2001:3::2
    proto esp spi 0xcae27194(3403837844) reqid 1(0x00000001) mode tunnel
    replay-window 0 seq 0x00000000 flag af-unspec (0x00100000)
    aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) 0xd8cd80445469ab67484a5b4e9e99ad3d3a55a6f1c131c6f8b82eb7648dbacf9844ab92f3 (288 bits) 128
    anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x362, bitmap 0x00000000
    if_id 0x63
    lifetime config:
      limit: soft (INF)(bytes), hard (INF)(bytes)
      limit: soft (INF)(packets), hard (INF)(packets)
      expire add: soft 3571(sec), hard 3960(sec)
      expire use: soft 0(sec), hard 0(sec)
    lifetime current:
      89840(bytes), 866(packets)
      add 2023-11-27 13:14:54 use 2023-11-27 13:15:07
    stats:
      replay-window 0 replay 0 failed 0
src 2001:3::2 dst 2001:3::3
    proto esp spi 0xcad3be8c(3402874508) reqid 1(0x00000001) mode tunnel
    replay-window 32 seq 0x00000000 flag af-unspec (0x00100000)
    aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) 0x5f678c6577e6290566783d136ce67419eab8d989ef2a9085cbcfb7417a997cbf90899686 (288 bits) 128
    anti-replay context: seq 0x35e, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0xffffffff
    if_id 0x63
    lifetime config:
      limit: soft (INF)(bytes), hard (INF)(bytes)
      limit: soft (INF)(packets), hard (INF)(packets)
      expire add: soft 3353(sec), hard 3960(sec)
      expire use: soft 0(sec), hard 0(sec)
    lifetime current:
      89600(bytes), 862(packets)
      add 2023-11-27 13:14:54 use 2023-11-27 13:14:55
    stats:
      replay-window 3 replay 2 failed 0
```

There are no xfrm error stats (client PC):

```
cat /proc/net/xfrm_stat
XfrmInError                 0
XfrmInBufferError           0
XfrmInHdrError              0
XfrmInNoStates              0
XfrmInStateProtoError       0
XfrmInStateModeError        0
XfrmInStateSeqError         0
XfrmInStateExpired          0
XfrmInStateMismatch         0
XfrmInStateInvalid          0
XfrmInTmplMismatch          0
XfrmInNoPols                0
XfrmInPolBlock              0
XfrmInPolError              0
XfrmOutError                0
XfrmOutBundleGenError       0
XfrmOutBundleCheckError     0
XfrmOutNoStates             0
XfrmOutStateProtoError      0
XfrmOutStateModeError       0
XfrmOutStateSeqError        0
XfrmOutStateExpired         0
XfrmOutPolBlock             0
XfrmOutPolDead              0
XfrmOutPolError             0
XfrmFwdHdrError             0
XfrmOutStateInvalid         0
XfrmAcquireError            0
```

No packet filtering going on (client PC):

```
ip6tables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

packets being counted (client PC):

```
ip6tables -v -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1999 packets, 316K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2817 packets, 382K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

policies look reasonable I think (client PC):

```
ip xfrm policy
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    dir out priority 399999 
    tmpl src 2001:3::3 dst 2001:3::2
        proto esp spi 0xcae27194 reqid 1 mode tunnel
    if_id 0x63
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    dir fwd priority 399999 
    tmpl src 2001:3::2 dst 2001:3::3
        proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
    if_id 0x63
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    dir in priority 399999 
    tmpl src 2001:3::2 dst 2001:3::3
        proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
    if_id 0x63
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0
```

monitor output (client PC):

```
ip xfrm monitor
Async event  (0x10)  replay update 
    src 2001:3::3 dst 2001:3::2  reqid 0x1 protocol esp  SPI 0xcae27194
Async event  (0x10)  replay update 
    src 2001:3::2 dst 2001:3::3  reqid 0x1 protocol esp  SPI 0xcad3be8c
Async event  (0x20)  timer expired 
    src 2001:3::3 dst 2001:3::2  reqid 0x1 protocol esp  SPI 0xcae27194
Async event  (0x20)  timer expired 
    src 2001:3::2 dst 2001:3::3  reqid 0x1 protocol esp  SPI 0xcad3be8c
```

So why doesn't the ping application receive the replies?
I've also tried running a client/server application (iperf) over the tunnel, with the same result, incoming packets received at the xfrm interface on the client PC are not received by the application.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Update - we found the problem. The replies coming through the tunnel had the Next Header field in the ESP Header set to value IPIP (0x04) instead of the expected value IPv6 (0x29).  We obtained an update for the router and everything now works correctly.